# How to check if view is created

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that implements a custom listener.

That fragment is replaced and added to the back stack using `addToBackStack()`

Now If I pop the backstack from the new fragment, I am calling my listener to do `someMethod()`. The problem is that method is associated with a view. Of course it will return an error since the view isn't created yet.

I am thinking of delaying that method with a Handler but that seems wrong. Is there any way I can pass my data to the previous fragment? or at least check if the view is created.

Here's my method when I replace/pop the fragment:

```
    String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();

    boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

    if (!fragmentPopped) { //fragment not in back stack, create it.
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

I have multiple fragments btw that may go back to the first fragment. So say I have 5 fragments.

A B C is the stack. I then go back to A using that method.

Comment: have you fixed your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your listener fragment be **fragment A**. You need to unsubscribe  fragment A in `onPause()` and subscribe in `onResume()`. 
Additionally, you need to trigger listener event immediately after someone subscribed to it if that event have already been fired (implement some boolean flag in your Model or something similar).

This way the event flow will be like this:

- A.onResume() - A.subscribe() [event wasn't fired, listener's not triggered]
- A.onPause() - A.unsubscribe()
- back pressed - your event fires
- A.onResume - A.subscribe() [event was fired, listener triggers. Your view is initialised at this point, everything works.]